# Create new activity from ImageButton in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-imagebutton

Im beginner and try to work on an app. I want to create a new page/activity when the `imageButton` on the `listView` is clicked. (The image is grab from url). Any help is appreciated.

Here is the`main.java`

```
public class IngredientCategoryMain extends Activity {

ListView list;
String[] title;
CategoryImageAdapter adapter;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ingredient_category_main);

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    title = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
    adapter=new CategoryImageAdapter(this, mStrings, title);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    list.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}

public View.OnClickListener listener=new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
};

public void onItemClick(int mPosition) {
    String tempValues = title[mPosition];
    Toast.makeText(IngredientCategoryMain.this, "You have clicked "+tempValues, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private String[] mStrings={
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/Ic_cake_48px.svg/2000px-Ic_cake_48px.svg.png",
        "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/04/01/21/30/can-99137_960_720.png",
        "http://publicdomainvectors.org/photos/Gerald_G_Fast_Food_Drinks_(FF_Menu)_9.png",
        "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/03/25/16/59/apple-297775_960_720.png",
        "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2012/04/16/11/14/mortar-35544_960_720.png",
        "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/13/10/05/cattle-156498_960_720.png",
        "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/12/15/39/acorn-150258_960_720.png",
        "http://publicdomainvectors.org/photos/johnny_automatic_bread_with_knife.png",
        "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/09/13/00/12/chicken-937584_960_720.jpg",
        "http://publicdomainvectors.org/photos/bowl-of-steaming-soup-01.png",
        "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/04/02/10/38/fish-304097_960_720.png",
        "http://publicdomainvectors.org/photos/Erbsen-lineart.png"
};

}
```

Adapter

```
public class CategoryImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

private Activity activity;
private String[] data;
private String[] title;


private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;


public CategoryImageAdapter(Activity a, String[] d, String[] t) {
    activity = a;
    title = t;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());


}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return title.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}


public static class ViewHolder {

    public ImageButton imageButton;
    public TextView textView;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ingcategoryrow, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.imageButton = (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();


    holder.textView.setText(title[position]);
    ImageButton imageButton = holder.imageButton;
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], imageButton);
    vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
    return vi;
}



private class OnItemClickListener implements OnClickListener{
    private int mPosition;

    OnItemClickListener(int position) {
        mPosition = position;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        IngredientCategoryMain sct = (IngredientCategoryMain)activity;
        sct.onItemClick(mPosition);

      }
    }
```

ImageLoader

```
public class ImageLoader {

MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
FileCache fileCache;
private Map<ImageButton, String> imageButtons = Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageButton, String>());
ExecutorService executorService;
Handler handler = new Handler();

public ImageLoader(Context context) {
    fileCache = new FileCache(context);
    executorService= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

}

final int stub_id=R.drawable.bakingood;

public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageButton imageButton) {
    imageButtons.put(imageButton, url);

    Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);

    if(bitmap!=null) {
        imageButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        queuePhoto(url, imageButton);
        imageButton.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageButton imageButton){
    PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageButton);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));

}

private class PhotoToLoad {
    public String url;
    public ImageButton imageButton;

    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageButton i) {
        url=u;
        imageButton=i;

    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {

        this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            if(imageButtonReused(photoToLoad))
                return;

            Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if(imageButtonReused(photoToLoad))
                return;

            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            handler.post(bd);

        } catch (Throwable th) {
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }

private  Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);
    Bitmap b= decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return  b;

    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        conn.disconnect();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);

        return bitmap;

    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        if(ex instanceof  OutOfMemoryError)
            memoryCache.clear();
        return null;
      }

    }


private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {

        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        FileInputStream stream1=new FileInputStream(f);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1,null,o);
        stream1.close();

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.

        // Set width/height of recreated image
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=85;

        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with current scale values
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        FileInputStream stream2=new FileInputStream(f);
        Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
        stream2.close();
        return bitmap;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

boolean imageButtonReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
    String tag=imageButtons.get(photoToLoad.imageButton);
    if (tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
}

class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {bitmap = b;photoToLoad = p;}

    public void run() {
        if (imageButtonReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if (bitmap!=null)
            photoToLoad.imageButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageButton.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
  }
}
```

MemoryCache

```
public class MemoryCache {

private static final String TAG = "MemoryCache";

private Map<String, Bitmap> cache = Collections.synchronizedMap(
        new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10,1.5f, true));

private long size=0;
private long limit=1000000;

public MemoryCache () {
    setLimit(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 4);
}

public void setLimit(long limit) {
    this.limit = limit;
    Log.i(TAG, "MemoryCache will use up to " + limit / 1024. / 1024. + "MB");

}

public Bitmap get(String id) {
    try {
        if (!cache.containsKey(id))
            return null;
        return cache.get(id);
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
      }
    }

public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap) {
    try{
        if(cache.containsKey(id))
            size-=getSizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
        cache.put(id, bitmap);
        size+=getSizeInBytes(bitmap);
        checkSize();
    }catch (Throwable th) {
        th.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

private void checkSize() {
    Log.i(TAG, "cache size="+size+" length="+cache.size());
    if(size>limit) {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Bitmap>> iter=cache.entrySet().iterator();

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, Bitmap> entry=iter.next();
            size-=getSizeInBytes(entry.getValue());
            iter.remove();
            if(size<=limit)
                break;
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Clean cache.New size "+cache.size());
        }
    }

public void clear() {
    try{
        cache.clear();
        size=0;
    }catch (NullPointerException ex) {

      }
    }

private long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (bitmap==null)
        return 0;
    return bitmap.getRowBytes()*bitmap.getHeight();
  }

}
```

FileCache

```
public class FileCache {
private File cacheDir;
public FileCache(Context context) {
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    {
        //if SDCARD is mounted (SDCARD is present on device and mounted)
        cacheDir = new File(
                android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"LazyList");
    }
    else
    {
        // if checking on simulator the create cache dir in your application context
        cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
    }

    if(!cacheDir.exists()){
        // create cache dir in your application context
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
      }
    }


public void clear() {
    File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
    if(files==null)
        return;
    for (File f:files)
        f.delete();
    }

public File getFile(String url) {
    //Identify images by hashcode or encode by URLEncoder.encode.
    String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());

    File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
    return f;
  }
}
```

Utils

```
public class Utils {
public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
{
    final int buffer_size=1024;
    try {
        byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
        for(;;) {
            int count = is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
            if (count == -1)
                break;
            os.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your adapter, after this line:

```
ImageButton imageButton = holder.imageButton;
```

do something like this:

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new.View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
Public void onClick(View :)
{
    Intent intent = New intent(activity,     ExampleActivityName.class);
    activity.startActivity(intent);

}

});
```

The way it works is that every view has an option to react to click events that the user performs ”on him”, all you need to do is to pass an implementation of the View.OnClickListener Interface to the View (via the setOnClickListener method) and that's it.
Second step is to start an activity which is faily easy, you need to create an intent with the current context and the class of the activity you wish to start, and than call the startActivity method from your current context.

In this case, the current context is represented by the activity reference.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the tip, can you guide me through the steps. Also, my imagebutton's image is from url. Thank you.

Comment: Hey Cassie, check my updated answer, in your case you can simply use the activity reference that you have inside the adapter, it is basically the same.

Comment: I dont find imageview on my adapter, do you mind to look at my adapter code above?

Comment: Thank you so much! I have another question, it seems like all the imageButtons linked to the same class. How can I do if I want each imageButton link to different classes.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what are you tried to achieve?

Comment: So I have 12 imageButtons on the listView and I want each imageButtons create new activity. How can I do that

Comment: You have the position of the current item which you are working on in this method, you can perform a switch case on that position integer to determine what activity you need to start, add the switch case inside the onClick method that we made.

Comment: Can you guide me through this. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

add the code of  'startActivity(intent)' in your listitem.onclick - you can check which image is being clicked or also the position and then launch the appropriate activity.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the tip, can you guide me through the steps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

after this line

```
ImageButton imageButton = holder.imageButton;
```

just add this lines of code

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, YourActivityClass.class));
            }
});
```

Comment: I have a list of imageButton, and each imagebutton will lead to new activity. keep in my that my imagebutton's image from url.

Comment: sorry its little mistakes. write activity instead of a

Comment: So I have 12 imageButtons on the listView and I want each imageButtons create new activity. How can I do that